# How to iterate through a dictionary in a dictionary in django template using django template tag?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, for-loop, jinja2

My dictionary looks like this:

```
a = {
            "1": {
                "league_id": "1",
                "name": "2018 Russia World Cup",
                "country": "World",
                "country_code": "",
                "season": "2018",
                "season_start": "2018-06-14",
                "season_end": "2018-07-15",
                "standings": False,
            },
            "2": {
                "league_id": "2",
                "name": "Premier League",
                "country": "England",
                "country_code": "GB",
                "season": "2018",
                "season_start": "2018-08-10",
                "season_end": "2019-05-12",
                "standings": True
            },
        }
```

I want to loop through the dict and display all values for "name" and "country".

my code in my .html template looks like:

```
          {% for c in a %}
                 <thead>{{ a[c]['country'] }}</thead>
          {% endfor %}

          {% for n in a %} 
            <tr>
                <td>{{  a[n]['name'] }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

This gave an error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '[c]['country']' from
>   'leagues[c]['country']'

I also tried

```
     {% for c in leagues %}
            <thead>{{ leagues.c.country }}</thead>
     {% endfor %}

     {% for n in leagues %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{  a.n.name }}</td>
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

It gave a blank page.

How do I target the values name and country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *not using Jinja*, you are using Django template language.

But this is not how you loop through dicts or lists in Python. When you do `for x in whatever`, `x` is *the actual element*, not the index. Also, when you want to loop through the values of a dict, you need to use the `values` method.

```
 {% for league in leagues.values %}
        <thead>{{ league.country }}</thead>
 {% endfor %}

 {% for league in leagues.values %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ league.name }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The loop works. Thanks on the jinja django template clarification, I'm am kinda new to django. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.